# SQL server 2008 date conversion formats

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I produce a CSV file but cannot figure out the proper date format.

I am aware of the MSDN site codes for datetime conversions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

It seems there is no code to convert my datetime into this format:
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MMAM
e.g.:
12/28/2014 4:33AM

How do you achieve such format?

Platform:
Microsoft SQL server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + 
        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100), 7)
```

Comment: excatly the output i wanted, and the shortest, still i wonder why SQL server has no such builtin code for it

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can use and is probably the most straightforward:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('0' + cast(month(dateColumn) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2) + '/' -- generate the day
  + RIGHT('0' + cast(day(dateColumn) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2) + '/'   -- generate the month
  + cast(year(dateColumn) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ' '                  -- generate the year
  + convert(VARCHAR, cast(dateColumn AS TIME)), 100)             -- generate the time
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 101) + ' ' + 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, GetDate())) + ':' + 
      RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, GetDate())), 2) AS TIME
```

EDIT: This gets the AM/PM also

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11),GETDATE(),101)
     + CONVERT(CHAR( 5),GETDATE(),114)
     + RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR( 5),GETDATE(),109), 2)
```

Comment: Actually, you format won't have the AM/PM suffix at the end.

Comment: somewhy its still doesnt produce the AM PM for me (even the edited one)

Answer (score -2):

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),3) as 'dd/MM/yy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) as 'dd/MM/yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),4) as 'dd.MM.yy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),104) as 'dd.MM.yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),5) as 'dd-MM-yy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105) as 'dd-MM-yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),6) as 'ddMonthyy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),106) as 'ddMonthyyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),7) as 'Monthdd.yy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),107) as 'Monthdd.yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),8) as 'hh.mm.ss'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),108) as 'hh.mm.ss'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),9) as 'Monthddyy hh.mm.ss.mss'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),109) as 'Monthddyyyy hh.mm.ss.mss'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),10) as 'mm-dd-yy'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),110) as  'mm-dd-yyyy'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),11) as 'yy/MM/dd'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),111) as  'yyyy/MM/dd'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),12) as 'yyMMdd'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),112) as  'yyyyMMdd'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),13) as 'ddMonthyy hh.mm.ss.mss'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),GETDATE(),113) as  'ddMonthyyyy hh.mm.ss.mss'

Comment: this thread is already answered, please do not flood it in hope of upvote ... also it begins with the "I am aware of the MSDN site codes"